# Getting CTRL+V to work in Vim inside Conemu

Tags: windows, vim, conemu

Conemu uses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> as the short cut to “paste first line of clipboad.” I *want* this functionality when I’m interacting with the command-line, but when I’m in Vim I’d like Vim to handle it.

Comment: Per-application hotkeys are not supported. Yet at least.

Comment: @Maximus any update on this? I don't care about using Ctrl-V outside of Vim.

Comment: Never mind, I added an answer that works for me.

Answer (score 18):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> instead.

Comment: I suppose that this is not so terrible.

Comment: A little terrible. Nice to know, though.

Answer (score 17):

For future Googlers, unbinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in Settings->Keys & Macro allows Vim to handle it. You can use right-click to paste instead.

Comment: right-click is not ctrl+v

Answer (score 1):

This is basically just a synthesis of the two other answers, but the workaround I ended up using was to go into `Settings`->`Keys & Macro` and change the binding for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `vim` inside of `ConEmu` why don't use `vim` key to paste from **system's clipboard** to `vim`.

Use `"*p` key combinations to paste in `vim`.